# Apache Ant version for java 10

Tags: java, ant, version, java-9, java-10

Is Ant 1.10.2 compatible with Java 10? The ant documentation is not very clear: it just says that it is compatible with a minimum version of Java 1.5. How can I be sure that it is compatible with java 10? Thank you!

Comment: *How can I be sure that it is compatible with java 10?* By giving it a try.

Comment: According to the https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.10.2.html they support Java 9. Java 10 is not much different so I would give it a try and in most cases if something supports Java 9 it should work in Java 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not explicitly listed as compatible with Java 10, but if you look at [release notes](https://archive.apache.org/dist/ant/RELEASE-NOTES-1.10.2.html) of latest Ant:

> - added "javac10+" as new supported value for javac's compiler attribute.
>
>   - javah has been removed from Java 10. The task will now throw an
>       exception if you try to use it while running Java 10 or newer.

So they mention Java 10 in regard to javac and javah, so I would assume it should work.